# matlab plot3 if z is not a function of F(x,y)

Tags: matlab

X and Y are matrix of 1*50000, I have already use plot(X,Y).

Z is the distance, it is a 1*30 matrix, it represents different x,y data at different length, and Z is independent of F(x,y).

For example, at Z=1 there is a graph of X,Y 
             at Z=1.7 there is another pair of X,Y, etc

so how can I tell matlab to do is, because in plot3 Z is a function of F(x,y)

thanks!

Comment: So you basically want to plot `X` and `Y` 30 times at different levels (`Z`)?

Comment: So you have 30 X,Y matrices? One X and Y for each element of Z? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: yeah, I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can use `meshgrid` to generate to required data. See my simple example below:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5];
Y = [3 2 1 9 5];
Z = [1 1.5 2];
[x,z] = meshgrid(X,Z);
[y,~] = meshgrid(Y,Z);
plot3(x',y','z')
```

[image: Sample run of the program.]

Comment: Interesting alternative! Clearly, we interpreted the question rather differently.

Comment: Yes, would even be more interesting what the correct interpretation is.

Comment: @2cents - I've voted for both your answers (i.e. you and Nemesis) because they're both valid interpretations.  I'd also like to see what the OP really means here. I hate these situations where the person providing the answer is faster than the person asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plot a set of points (X,Y) for each element of Z, this is pretty straightforward. You just need to copy the element of Z for each point in (X,Y)

```
Z = 1:30;

figure; 
hold on;

% I'm only plotting the first two elements of Z for simplicity
% Change the length of the for loop to plot them all 
for ii=1:2
    % I randomly initialize (X,Y) for demonstration purposes, 
    % but you would probably load them from somewhere else.
    X = rand(1 ,500);
    Y = rand(1, 500);

    scatter3(X, Y, reshape(repmat(Z(ii), 500, 1), 1, []));
    % You could also use plot3   
    % Rotate the resulting figure to see both layers
end
```

If you can also concatenate your (X,Y) sets for efficiency,

```
% In your code, X1, X2, and Y1, Y2 should correspond to the (X,Y) pairs 
% for the first two elements of Z   
X = [X1; X2];
Y = [Y1; Y2];
Z = 1:2;
scatter3(X(:), Y(:), reshape(repmat(Z, 1, 500), 1000, []));
```